# Vuex-Persistedstate run mutation on reload

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt-i18n, vuex4

I'm using Nuxt 2, Vue 2, Vuex 3, Vuetify 2, vuex-persistedstate 4 and nuxt-i18n 6.

I set this plugin to persiste my Vuex state which is containing **RTL status** and **language code**:

`plugins/persistedState.client.js`:

```js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
export default ({ store, req, vuetify, $vuetify }) => {
  createPersistedState({
    paths: [
      'app.isRTL',
      'app.langCode'
    ]
  })(store)
}
```

Also, I write some mutaion to save this settings in state and apply theme to vuetify:

`store/app/index.js`:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    isRTL: false,
    langCode: 'en'
  },
  mutations: {
    setRTL: function (state, isRTL) {
      this.app.vuetify.framework.rtl = isRTL
      state.isRTL = isRTL
  },
    setLangCode: function (state, langCode) {
      this.app.vuetify.framework.lang.current  = langCode
      state.langCode = langCode
  },
  }
}
```

- by calling the `setLangCode` mutation, the language will be set to given language and save that in the sate
- by calling `setRTL` rtl direction of vuetify will set correctly and save that in the sate

Theproblem is that on page reload vuex-persistedstate will restore the vuex state from local storage but **the mutaion that sets the vuetify settings won't get called**, so the vuetify will stay on the worng direction.

Also, the nuxt-i18n will detect the language code from the url **not from the state** and translates the page base on that.